# Are the Latin word "octo" is derived from the serial number of the letter "h" in the alpabet?

Tags: etymology

Are the Latin word "octo" is derived from the serial number of the letter "h" in the alpabet?

The latin words "veho" and "traho" transform into the latin words "vecto" and "tracto" respectively by analogy with the English word "bear" transforms into the English word "bring". The latin language also has the word "octo". I have tried to reconstruate it origin.

```
    The origin verb   The perfect passive participle   The derivative verb
     veho                      vectus                        vecto
     traho                     tractus                       tracto
     ?oho?                     ?octus?                       octo

a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
```

For better understanding the question:

```
The origin verb   The past passive participle       The derivative verb     
      bear                     born                          bring
```

Comment: Seeing as _octō_ doesn't have an H in it, and also isn't a verb, I'm not sure why it would be connected?

Comment: Why are you only looking at first person singular forms of the verbs? The word *octo* does not have forms like *octare*, *octemus*, and *octa*. The question would make much more sense to me if *octo* was a verb, but it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

*Octō* comes from the dual of an old PIE stem `*oḱto-` meaning "four fingers" (compare Avestan *ašti-* "four fingerwidths" which has gone through satemization). The alphabet came much later.

Comment: For similarities, cf. *duo* and *ambo*. *Octo* is of the same variety.